# Android: checking database with volley library constantly

Tags: android, authentication, android-volley

I started learning Android and Java a week ago and now I am trying to make an login application. I am using Volley libary to communicate with my server. I have done the login part. Now, what I want to do is to check the database every minute to see if the password or the username somehow changed. If the information in the database is changed, app will automaticly logout the user.

If you can explain which tools(Services,BroadcastReceivers) I can use and how can I achieve it, as I am not very experienced.

This is what I tried and failed:

loginChecker.class

```
public class loginChecker extends Service {
    public loginChecker() {
    }
    public static String username;
    public static String password;

    private loginChecker mInstance = this;
    public  static boolean loginCheck= true;
    public static String responseG = "failed";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
        username = b.getString("username");
        password = b.getString("password");

        final String URL = ".........";
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mInstance);


        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {

                do{
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            responseG = response;
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            responseG = "error";
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hashMap.put("username", username);
                            hashMap.put("password", password);
                            return hashMap;
                        }
                    };

                    requestQueue.add(request);
                    switch(responseG){
                        case "successful" :
                            loginCheck = true;
                            break;
                        case "failed" :
                            loginCheck= false;
                            break;
                        case "error" :
                            loginCheck = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                while(loginCheck == true || responseG == "successful");
                }
        }).start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOOP ENDED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        final Intent mainActivity = new Intent(mInstance, MainActivity.class);
        mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(mainActivity);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static final String URL = "........";
    private StringRequest request;
    private TextView text;
    private EditText userName, passWord;
    private Button loginButton;
    public MainActivity mInstance = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        final Intent profilePage = new Intent(this, Profile.class);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick (View v){
                                           loginButton.setEnabled(false);
                                           request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                   text.setText(response);
                                                   switch(response){
                                                       case "successful" :

                                                           Intent loginCheckerService = new Intent(mInstance, com.erenyenigul.apps.starter.services.loginChecker.class);
                                                           Bundle b = new Bundle();
                                                           b.putString("username", String.valueOf(userName.getText()));
                                                           b.putString("password", String.valueOf(passWord.getText()));
                                                           loginCheckerService.putExtras(b);
                                                           startService(loginCheckerService);
                                                           startActivity(profilePage);
                                                           finish();
                                                           break;
                                                       case "failed" :
                                                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username or Password you entered is wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                           loginButton.setEnabled(true);
                                                           break;
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is a problem with our servers or you don't have internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                               }
                                           }) {
                                               @Override
                                               protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                                                   HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                                   hashMap.put("username", userName.getText().toString());
                                                   hashMap.put("password", passWord.getText().toString());
                                                   return hashMap;
                                               }
                                           };

                                           requestQueue.add(request);
                                       }
                                   }
        );
    }
}
```

There is also a file called Profile.class but it is empty. I tried this but the loop lasted one tour. It stopped even though the connection was ok and the data wasn't changed.

Comment: You can use Thread, or a Service, or any non "main thread" to query for that data. Since there are too many options, you must describe what you already attempted and what failed. Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: you name your service class in lower case?

Comment: i had no errors because of the name